# How to make a text blink in shell script

Tags: bash, blink

I have this piece of code below:

`echo "\033[33mTitle of the Program\033[0m"`

which changes the colour to yellow.

How can I make the text "Title of the Program" blink?

Answer (score 52):

### Try adding `-e` if it's not working without it

You may need to add the `-e` option to `echo` (at least that's required on all or most systems I use).  The following will tell your system to blink the text:

```
echo  -e "\033[5mTitle of the Program\033[0m"
```

### You can have blinking *and* color

And you don't have to choose *either* yellow *or* blinking.  You can have your cake and eat it too:

```
echo  -e "\033[33;5mTitle of the Program\033[0m"
```

### Some systems ignore blink codes

Your system may ignore the blink code—this appears to be quite common.  If you want to make the text prominent, but blinking is being ignored, you can instead invert the colors with `7`:

```
echo  -e "\033[33;7mTitle of the Program\033[0m"
```

Or you can use blinking *and* inversion of colors (and yellow):

```
echo  -e "\033[33;5;7mTitle of the Program\033[0m"
```

Comment: not working with my bash :(

Answer (score 23):

Whether you can make *blink* work or not depends upon the *terminal emulator*.  The ***system*** itself is irrelevant.

The example given in the question was close, needing only a change to the escape sequence to "work" with any [POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html):

```
echo  "\033[33;5mTitle of the Program\033[0m"
```

The **`-e`** suggested is unneeded (it is a *bashism*, non-standard, and usually unneeded).  Changing the **`7`** (reverse) to **`5`** (blink) does what was asked.

Rather than hardcoding the escape, you could use [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html), e.g.,

```
printf '%s%s%s%s' "$(tput setaf 3)" "$(tput blink)" "Title of the Program" "$(tput sgr0)"
```

for the same effect, with two differences:

- the expression is arguably more readable,
- actually uses the known terminal capabilities, but
- assumes you are using a suitable terminal description, i.e., `$TERM`.

For example VTE (the library used for various [***skins***](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/skin) such as gnome-terminal) does not support blink (and it's possible to find its developers' opinions on the topic in various bug reports).  Using [`infocmp`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html) to display the corresponding terminal capabilities shows that, plus some other differences:

```
$ infocmp vte xterm
comparing vte to xterm.
    comparing booleans.
        km: F:T.
        mc5i: F:T.
        npc: F:T.
    comparing numbers.
    comparing strings.
        blink: NULL, '\E[5m'.
        cnorm: '\E[?25h', '\E[?12l\E[?25h'.
        cvvis: NULL, '\E[?12;25h'.
        enacs: '\E)0', NULL.
        is2: '\E[m\E[?7h\E[4l\E>\E7\E[r\E[?1;3;4;6l\E8', '\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>'.
        kb2: '\E[E', '\EOE'.
        kfnd: '\E[1~', NULL.
        kslt: '\E[4~', NULL.
        mc0: NULL, '\E[i'.
        mc4: NULL, '\E[4i'.
        mc5: NULL, '\E[5i'.
        rep: NULL, '%p1%c\E[%p2%{1}%-%db'.
        rmacs: '^O', '\E(B'.
        rmcup: '\E[2J\E[?47l\E8', '\E[?1049l'.
        rmm: NULL, '\E[?1034l'.
        rs2: '\E7\E[r\E8\E[m\E[?7h\E[!p\E[?1;3;4;6l\E[4l\E>\E[?1000l\E[?25h', '\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>'.
        setb: NULL, '\E[4%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m'.
        setf: NULL, '\E[3%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m'.
        sgr: '\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p5%t;2%;%?%p7%t;8%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;m%?%p9%t\016%e\017%;', '%?%p9%t\E(0%e\E(B%;\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p5%t;2%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p7%t;8%;m'.
        sgr0: '\E[0m\017', '\E(B\E[m'.
        smacs: '^N', '\E(0'.
        smcup: '\E7\E[?47h', '\E[?1049h'.
        smm: NULL, '\E[?1034h'.
```

If you happen to use KDE `konsole`, the differences are longer (although `konsole` happens to support *blink*).

Answer (score 5):

Just use `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
printf "\e[6;33mTitle of the Program\e[0m"
```

This line prints `Title of the Program` with yellow, blinking text.

Answer (score 3):

A small work around to make the line blink in bash script

```
for (( i=0;i<=3;i++))
do
#Below line will deleted the before printed line
echo -en "\033[1A"
echo -en "EmpNo:$empno already exists\n";
sleep 0.4s;
#Below line to print a blank line
echo -en "\033[1A"
echo -en "                                                            \n";                                                                         
sleep 0.2s;
done
echo -en "\033[2A"
echo -en "                                                            \n";
echo -en "\033[1A"
echo -en "Enter the empno       : "; read empno1;
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it's meant to be:

```
echo " \033[5mTitle of the Program\033[0m"
```

The only change is before the title, the 33m is replaced by 5m. See [Ansi Escape Codes](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/ansi_escapes.html)

Note that some systems filter out blink, because it's really annoying. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: What does `tput blink` produce for you?  You might want to convert to hex by piping to `od`, `hexdump`, `xxd`, or a similar tool: `tput blink | xxd`

Comment: I just ran tput blink, and it produced the equivalent (and didn't work). Most terminals don't support blink, because it's annoying.

Comment: "Many people (myself included) object strongly to the "blink" attribute. Fortunately, it doesn't work in any terminal emulators that I'm aware of." -- http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-6.html

Comment: Just throwing this out there but the IBM 3161 terminal next to me *does* support blinking. I just spent about half an hour figuring out why irssi's default theme was making blinking text everywhere. (if anyone finds this through google, the solution is this theme https://github.com/asenchi/irssi-theme-doc/blob/master/colorless.theme )

Comment: http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting#terminals_compatibility ... konsole and xterm support blinking according to this list. I tested konsole and it works.

Comment: blink doesn't work on VTE, You have to use `xterm` instead of ANSI or `tput`

Comment: @PersianGulf - that's what I meant when I said "Note that some systems filter out blink, because it's really annoying. Your mileage may vary."

Answer (score 1):

1. export variables

```
export YELLOWIT="\e[1;3;5;43m"
export NC="\e[0m"
```

2. use in `echo` to get desired effects

```
echo -e "\n${YELLOWIT}### RESTORE FROM USB - Firefox Bookmarks ###${NC}\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

`\033[0;5m` is supposed to be "slow blink" and `\033[0;6m` is supposed to be "rapid blink" but I haven't had any success with rapid blink.

---

Just wanted to add my cheat sheet as an answer. Results differ between terminals so you can use this the verify your terminal. This was built using personal experience and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code. Just save it to your local machine and `sh <filename>.sh` to see all the pretty colors.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "\033[0;0m -- 0 » no style --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;1m -- 1 » white:bolded --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;2m -- 2 » white:dimmed --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;3m -- 3 » white:italic --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;4m -- 4 » white:underline --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;5m -- 5 » white:slow blink --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;6m -- 6 » white:rapid blink --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;7m -- 7 » white background aka 'invert' --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;8m -- 8 » hidden --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;9m -- 9 » white 'alternate font' --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;10m -- 10 » white 'alternate font' --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;11m -- 11 » white 'alternate font' --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;12m -- 12 » white 'alternate font' --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;13m -- 13 » white 'alternate font' --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;14m -- 14 » white 'alternate font' --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;15m -- 15 » white 'alternate font' --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;16m -- 16 » white 'alternate font' --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;17m -- 17 » white 'alternate font' --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;18m -- 18 » white 'alternate font' --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;19m -- 19 » white 'alternate font' --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;20m -- 20 » white:Gothic --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;21m -- 20 » white:double underline --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;22m -- 20 » white:normal intensity --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;23m -- 20 » white:Neither italic, nor blackletter --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;24m -- 20 » white:Not underlined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;25m -- 20 » white:Not blinking --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;26m -- 20 » white:Proportional spacing --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;27m -- 20 » white:Not reversed --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;28m -- 20 » white:Reveal --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;29m -- 20 » white:Not crossed out --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;30m -- 30 » black --\033[0;0m (-- 30 » black --) "
echo "\033[0;31m -- 31 » red --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;32m -- 32 » green --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;33m -- 33 » yellow --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;34m -- 34 » blue --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;35m -- 35 » magenta --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;36m -- 36 » teal --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;37m -- 37 » grey --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;38m -- 38 » white --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;39m -- 39 » white/default color --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;40m -- 40 » black background? --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;41m -- 41 » red background --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;42m -- 42 » green background --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;43m -- 43 » yellow background --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;44m -- 44 » blue background --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;45m -- 45 » magenta background --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;46m -- 46 » teal background --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;47m -- 47 » grey background --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;48m -- 48 » Set background color --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;49m -- 49 » default background --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;50m -- 50 » Disable proportional spacing --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;51m -- 51 » Framed --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;52m -- 52 » Encircled --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;53m -- 53 » Overlined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;54m -- 54 » Neither framed nor encircled --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;55m -- 55 » Not overlined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;56m -- 56 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;57m -- 57 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;58m -- 58 » Set underline color --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;59m -- 59 » Default underline color --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;60m -- 60 » Ideogram underline or right side line --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;61m -- 61 » Ideogram double underline, or double line on the right side --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;62m -- 62 » Ideogram overline or left side line --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;63m -- 63 » Ideogram double overline, or double line on the left side --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;64m -- 64 » Ideogram stress marking --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;65m -- 65 » No ideogram attributes --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;66m -- 66 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;67m -- 67 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;68m -- 68 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;69m -- 69 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;70m -- 70 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;71m -- 71 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;72m -- 72 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;73m -- 73 » Superscript --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;74m -- 74 » Subscript --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;75m -- 75 » Neither superscript nor subscript --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;76m -- 76 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;77m -- 77 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;78m -- 78 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;79m -- 79 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;80m -- 80 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;81m -- 81 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;82m -- 82 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;83m -- 83 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;84m -- 84 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;85m -- 85 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;86m -- 86 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;87m -- 87 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;88m -- 88 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;89m -- 89 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;90m -- 90 » Set bright foreground color - grey --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;91m -- 91 » Set bright foreground color - red --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;92m -- 92 » Set bright foreground color - green --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;93m -- 93 » Set bright foreground color - yellow --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;94m -- 94 » Set bright foreground color - blue --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;95m -- 95 » Set bright foreground color - magenta --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;96m -- 96 » Set bright foreground color - teal --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;97m -- 97 » Set bright foreground color - white --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;98m -- 98 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;99m -- 99 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;100m -- 100 » Set bright background color - grey --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;101m -- 101 » Set bright background color - red --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;102m -- 102 » Set bright background color - green --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;103m -- 103 » Set bright background color - yellow --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;104m -- 104 » Set bright background color - blue --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;105m -- 105 » Set bright background color - magenta --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;106m -- 106 » Set bright background color - teal --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;107m -- 107 » Set bright background color - white --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;108m -- 108 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
echo "\033[0;109m -- 109 » undefined --\033[0;0m"
```