# Blinking text in shell script (Putty;Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, console, putty, tail

I am tailing a file using Putty.

I have this code:

```
tail -f /srv/ppp/ppp*.log | perl -pe 's/(TransactionID)/\e[4;38;5;255m$&\e[0m/g';
```

The following code makes the string "TransactionID" underlined and adds a color.
My question is how can I also make the "TransactionID" string blink?

I couldn't find practical solutions to my issue in other similar posts...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-to-make-a-text-blink-in-shell-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439482/how-to-make-a-text-blink-in-shell-script).

Comment: No - this doesnt solve my problem as I still cant make it to blink.

Comment: Then your question must say that you also tried this and it did't not work. And actually your question would better fit on [su], where you may get more attention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a text blink in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439482/how-to-make-a-text-blink-in-shell-script)

Comment: No this still don't seem to work

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that your PuTTY configuration needs a switch to enable blinking text?  I ask because the PuTTY Configuration on a Windows system has an explicit checkbox to "Enable Blinking text" in its "Terminal" configuration settings.

Answer (score 1):

In putty:

TERMINAL -> ENABLE BLINKING TEXT